# Recursion query?

Tags: mongodb, recursion, hierarchy

I'm new to mongodb.

Let's say I have a "file system" hierarchy in my database:

```
db.directories.save({ _id: "root", directories: ["src", "lib"], files: ["config.cfg"] })
db.directories.save({ _id: "src", directories: [], files: ["file1.js", "file2.js"] })
db.directories.save({ _id: "lib", directories: [], files: [] })

db.files.save({ _id: "config.cfg", size: 2310 })
db.files.save({ _id: "file1.js", size: 5039 })
db.files.save({ _id: "file2.js", size: 1299 })
```

How would I get the total size of a folder?

i.e. total size of "root" directory = total size of files + total size of subdirectories

Comment: Usually you would design your schema based on queries you want to run, not the other way around.  In current schema there is no way to do what you want in a single query.

Comment: What schema would you suggest instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question about what schema would best fit the type of access pattern you describe an answered in some example talks about how to represent a hierarchy in MongoDB/document database.

A common answer that works for a lot of different queries is where you store in each file its name, size, direct parent and array of all of its ancestors.

That would make your sample data:

```
db.files.save({ _id: "root"})
db.files.save({ _id: "src", parent: "root", ancestors: ["root"] } )
db.files.save({ _id: "lib", parent: "root", ancestors: ["root"]} )
db.files.save({ _id: "config.cfg", parent: "root", ancestors: ["root"], size: 2310 })
db.files.save({ _id: "file1.js", parent: "src", ancestors: ["root","src"], size: 5039 })
db.files.save({ _id: "file2.js", parent: "src", ancestors: ["root","src"], size: 1299 })
```

Now if you want to query for things like "Files in this directory" or "all files under this directory (including recursively)" you query:

```
db.files.find( { parent: "root" } )    // all files in /src directory
db.files.find( {ancestors: "root"} )   // all files under /root directory tree
```

Since you need to use aggregation framework to get things like sum, the query for size of folder would be:

```
db.files.aggregate([
       {$match:{ancestors:"src"}}, 
       {$group:{
           _id:   "src",
           total_size:  {$sum:"$size"}
          }
       }
]);
```

To see size of all folders which are in root folder it would be:

```
db.files.aggregate([
       {$match:{ancestors:"root"}}, 
       {$group:{
           _id:   "root",
           total_size:  {$sum:"$size"}
          }
       }
]);
```

Comment: Your example helped me a lot