# How to do recursive CTE ( SQL server Equivalent ) in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, recursive-query, nosql

Does MongoDB have something similar to what the SQL standard calls recursive CTEs (Common Table Expression)? 
You can see a SQL Server example of this halfway down [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29127163/sql-server-bom-recursion-from-the-bottom-up) page.

Comment: Please add your schema and sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like $graphLookup might be what you're looking for. Check the manual [graphLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/)

Comment: awesome!  new feature.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly duplicate
[Recursion query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845585/recursion-query)

There's no straight conversion between Relational Model and Document Model.
you have to change your table structure.